# Word was unable to read this document. It may be corrupt

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, ms-word

I have an asp.net application which uses a word template that generates a document attachment in an email.  Originally I had the template on my local drive for testing, but now that I prepare to place the application on our server for testing I’ve run into a problem.  If I place the template in a folder within the application (still running from Visual studio) or on a network drive I receive the error:

```
Word was unable to read this document.  It may be corrupt.\nTry one or more of the following:\n* Open and Repair the file.\n* Open the file with the Text Recovery converter."}
Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
ErrorCode: -2146823137
HResult: -2146823137
HelpLink: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\1033\\WDMAIN11.CHM#24631"
InnerException: null
Message: "Word was unable to read this document.  It may be corrupt.\nTry one or more of the following:\n* Open and Repair the file.\n* Open the file with the Text Recovery converter."
```

I have Word 2007 on my desktop.  I can open the document fine by double clicking it on the network drive.  I’ve tried changing the extension to .dot from .dotx & even renaming the file– didn’t do anything.  The results of my searching online either didn’t pertain to me or didn’t help (permissions issue, but I receive error with template in application itself).

My Code:

```
object templateDoc = "\\network path\\ServiceRequestForm.dotx";
            object outputDoc = @"C:\temp\ServiceRquestFormOutput.docx";
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Add(ref templateDoc, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            doc.Activate();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find fnd = wordApp.Selection.Find;

            SearchReplace(fnd, wordApp, "%date%", date);
            SearchReplace(fnd, wordApp, "%routingto%", routingTo);
```

Error is from line:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Add(ref templateDoc, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

As far as me using MS.Office.Interop.Word...to do this, don’t ask me why I’m not doing it this way, that way, your way, whatever way…if you don’t have anything that can help move on.  I appreciate any advice that anyone can add. Thanks.

Comment: Try opening a plain .txt file from the same network location...see if that fails too.  I'm guessing that your app pool user doesn't have permissions to the folder.

Comment: I added a plain txt file to my application (w/in VS) and tried to add that (wordApp.Documents.Add(ref textfile...) and received same error.

Comment: I was thinking of just using `System.IO.File.OpenText("\\NetworkShare\File.txt")` just to isolate the problem.  If that fails, it has nothing to do with Word or your code... it's probably a permissions issue.

Comment: I tried that with the exception of the file is in in my application (not network) and I did not receive any error.  Has something to do with the document itself.  I set every permission//access to the folder with that document that I can think off.  This is so frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as embarrassing as this is to admit, I didn't have my document checked into source control.  Once I did the error went away and I have no more problems(as of now!).  Yeah...ugh!